# Enumerate not using the correct number format

Tags: beamer, formatting, numbering, enumerate

I am using `beamer` to type slides. Recently, I reinstalled AucTeX and now the numbers don't look right. I use `\begin{enumerate}[1.]` so that it will print `1.`, `2.`, etc. instead of the numbers with the circles around them. But, after the reinstallation, it is doing the circles, even for the exact same files where it was okay before even with TeXshop on a Mac.

My example code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}


%PACKAGES
\usepackage{multimedia,pdfpages,mathtools,enumerate}
\usepackage{empheq}
\geometry{paperwidth=7.5in,paperheight=10.5in}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{comment,multicol,graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{pdfsync}




%SETTING THEME
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\definecolor{Halloween}{RGB}{250,155,30}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}



\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode
}



\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\setbeamersize{text margin left=.5 cm, text margin right=.5 cm} 


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{example}
  \begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item La
    \item La La
  \end{enumerate}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal example which reproduces your error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use the [`enumerate` package](//ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) with [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer) since it provides *template*s to set these things. Specifically, you're interested in the `[default]` template for `enumerate item`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item La
    \item La La
  \end{enumerate}

  \setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[default]

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item La
    \item La La
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```